# Reqest to CDYNE results in urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to use python for address verification using `CDYNE` service.

I used [this](http://pav3.cdyne.com/Pavservice.svc/help/operations/VerifyAddressAdvanced) as reference to create `POST` request and it looks like following

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = 'http://pav3.cdyne.com/PavService.svc/VerifyAddressAdvanced'
data = {}

data['CityName'] = 'San Francisco'
data['FirmOrRecipient'] = 'CDYNE'
data['LicenseKey'] = 'valid_key'
data['PrimaryAddressLine'] = '45 fremont street'
data['ReturnCaseSensitive'] = True
data['ReturnCensusInfo'] = True
data['ReturnCityAbbreviation'] = True
data['ReturnGeoLocation'] = True
data['ReturnLegislativeInfo'] = True
data['ReturnMailingIndustryInfo'] = True
data['ReturnResidentialIndicator'] = True
data['ReturnStreetAbbreviated'] = True
data['SecondaryAddressLine'] = ''
data['State'] = 'CA'
data['Urbanization'] = ''
data['ZipCode'] = '94105'
```

and post the request as following

```
data_encoded = urllib.urlencode(data)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data_encoded)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I see error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 398, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 511, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 436, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 370, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I am new to this so don't understand what has gone wrong, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either have to send the request as `json` or `xml` formatted document, the schema is on the page you've linked to. 
you're sending an urlencoded request, which isn't supported by the api.

edit: that's how it would look like using `JSON`:

```
import json
data_encoded = json.dumps(data)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data_encoded, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
# ...
```

Comment: Mata, how do I do that? I do not see the way to do it